# Will the clojure compiler automatically evaluate expressions of literals at compile time?

Tags: compiler-construction, clojure

This might be a silly question, but:

Suppose an expression depends only on literals, or on other expressions that also only depend on literals; will the compiler evaluate this at compile time?

Suppose I have,

```
(def a (some-time-consuming-function some-literal))

(def b (some-other-time-consuming-function a))
```

Will both b and a be evaluated completely at compile time, so that the User isn't affected?

EDIT: Thanks very much, all of the answers were very helpful.

**EDIT 6.6.2011:**  Turns out that if you try and use this technique to precompute a very large data structure, it's easy to make class files that are too big to load.  In those cases you want to create a file which will be read in rather than a class file that will be loaded.  The macro tricks described in these answers should only be applied as is in situations where the return value is not a prohibitively large structure.

The error thrown is: "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid this class index"
See [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/clojure@googlegroups.com/msg01009.html) for discussion of a related situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not silly at all, I had to think about it and test it out.

It will work only if you use macros instead of functions, since the body of a macro is evaluated at compile/macroexpansion-time.  E.g.:

```
(defmacro preprocess [f & args]
  (let [x# (apply (resolve f) args)]
    `~x#))

(def a (preprocess some-time-consuming-function some-literal))

(def b (preprocess some-other-time-consuming-function a))
```

Then `a` and `b` are `def`'d to the values returned from evaluating `preprocess`.

Comment: I thought that macros might be a way around this.  Three questions: 1. How did you go about testing this?  (I thought about using the Ackerman function, and seeing at what point in the process I noticed a slowdown, but I don't know what the most rigorous way of doing this is.)  2. When is b evaluated -- at load time?  3. Don't the the sytax quote and unquote symbols cancel each other out?  Anyway, thanks very much for the answer!

Comment: 1) I tested it by using a different metric, namely a function that called println.  The message appears during compile but doesn't appear when loading the compiled namespace, thus one can conclude that the function was not being run at runtime. 2) The value being assigned to the var b is evaluated during macroexpansion. 3) Yep. It was mistakenly left over from an earlier iteration.

Comment: To be clear though, the answer to your question is "no."  It's just that there are ways to achieve such behavior when you want to.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, there is a pretty important reason why the right-hand-sides of `def`s need to be evaluated at load time: they might depend on the environment somehow and in the general case it's impossible to tell whether they do or not. Take e.g.

```
(def *available-processors* (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))
```

Secondly, here's one approach to testing what actually happens:

1. Create a test project with Leiningen -- say, `lein new testdefs`.
2. Put `:main testdefs.core` in `project.clj`.
3. Put the following in `src/testdefs/core.clj`:

   ```
   (ns testdefs.core
     (:gen-class))

   (defn take-your-time [t]
     (printf "Taking my time (%d)...\n" t)
     (Thread/sleep t))

   (def a (take-your-time 5000))

   (defmacro frozen-def [v e]
     (let [val (eval e)]
       `(def ~v ~val)))

   (frozen-def b (take-your-time 5000))

   (defn -main [& args]
     (println "Starting...")
     (println a)
     (println b))
   ```
4. Run `lein uberjar`; surely enough, the code takes its time twice.
5. Run `java -jar testdefs-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`; you'll notice the code only takes its time once.

Comment: Sorry for the weird spacing in the code -- looks like some SO Markdown weirdness or not-so-great Markdown-fu on my part (the second possibility seems more likely).

Comment: I can't believe that I forgot that there's a sleep function.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the time-consuming functions are called only once, when your code is loaded.

The Clojure compiler does not try to optimize constant expressions, but the Java JIT compiler may do so in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

For the examples given, the expressions are evaluated at compile/load time. `def` *always* evaluates its second argument. From [special forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28def%20symbol%20init?%29)

```
(def symbol init?)
```

Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of `symbol` and a namespace of the value of the current namespace `*ns*`. **If `init` is supplied, it is evaluated**, and the root binding of the var is set to the resulting value.